# Make two elements in div hover together

Tags: html, css

I have a div with two a elements in it. I want it so if you hover on one of the a elements both of them change color. I figured applying the div to the CSS class would make it work but it still only changes one.

```css
div.test-hover :hover {
  color: #f20d20;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-hover">
  <a class="article-title" href="google.com">This is main title</a>
  <br/>
  <a class="article-title" href="google.com">title</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with your current code is the `div.test-hover :hover` selector is styling child elements that are hovered.  However, what you seem to want is just style the `a` tags inside of `div.test-hover` when the wrapper `div` is hovered.  Here is a snippet with the fixed code:

```css
.test-hover:hover a {
  color: #f20d20;
}
```

```html
<div class="test-hover">                                        
    <a class="article-title" href="google.com">This is main title</a>
    <br/>
    <a class="article-title" href="google.com">title</a>
</div>
```